# Why is the following code throwing an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

So, I am trying to define a function which would invert a binary tree, and when I run the below code, and then execute `a_node.binInversion()`, I get the error which says, "NameError: name 'binInversion' is not defined". Why is that error happening?

The code I'm executing is as below:

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert_left(self, value):
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = BinaryTree(value)

        else:
            new_node = BinaryTree(value)
            new_node.left = self.left
            self.left = new_node
    
    def insert_right(self, value):
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = BinaryTree(value)

        else:
            new_node = BinaryTree(value)
            new_node.right = self.right
            self.right = new_node
    
    def binInversion(self):

        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            return 0

        else:
            binInversion(self.left)
            binInversion(self.right)
            self.left, self.right = self.right, self.left

a_node = BinaryTree('a')
a_node.insert_left('b')
a_node.insert_right('c')

b_node = a_node.left
b_node.insert_right('d')


c_node = a_node.right
c_node.insert_left('e')
c_node.insert_right('f')

d_node = b_node.right
e_node = c_node.left
f_node = c_node.right

a_node.binInversion()
```

Also, I know that there are high chances of `binInversion()` function not working as expected. Please **DO NOT** disclose the solution for inverting a binary tree, as I want to give it a shot on my own before looking at the solution.

Comment: You didn't define `binInversion`. Did you mean: `self.binInversion()`?

Comment: As quarama said. There is a problem in `binInversion`. Shall `binInversion` really be called recursively? If it does, then apparently it should not take an argument but in your code it does...

Comment: @quamrana I am not following. The definition is right there in the code.

Comment: Yes, but you can't access it using the code you show. Did you mean: `self.binInversion()`?

Comment: @quamrana Can you please explain why is it not accessible? Are you suggesting that it is not accessible because it is an instance method and rather suggesting me to convert it to a class method?

Comment: You have defined `binInversion()` as a member of your class and there are two ways of accessing it. Just writing `binInversion(self.left)` is not one of them. What you *can* do is to write `self.binInversion()` as I have already suggested twice before. Or, more unusually, `BinaryTree.binInversion(self)`.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your input. I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few bugs here:

1. binInversion is not a function, it is a class method, remember to call `self.binInversion()` instead of `binInversion()`
2. after the above fix, there will still be an error that says something along the lines of binInversion was given too many arguments. Your  method of binInversion takes no arguments, try something like `def binInversion(self, node)` to pass in another argument or node.

Comment: Well it is the same method like the other two, i.e. "insert_left" and "insert_right". Also I want it to be object method as opposed to class method, so as to have the flexibility of inverting a tree starting at a particular node rather than always invert the whole tree starting at root. I am not exactly following.